# How to select default date in a date range in datetimepicker ?

Tags: jquery

I am developing the MVC application, I am using datepicker in it.
I want to set the range of 1930 to 1995 in the datepicker.
I want to set the selected date is 1/1/1995

I have written the following code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {


        $(function () {
            $('.BirthDate').datepicker({
                dateFormat: "dd-M-y",
                yearRange:'1930:1995',
                buttonImage: '@Url.Content("~/Resource/Calender.jpg")',
                buttonImageOnly: true
            });
        });

        $(".BirthDate" ).datepicker( "setDate", "01/01/1995" );
      });
```

But its not working...
What changes i have to made ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `defaultDate` option:

Specify either an actual date via a Date object or as a string in the current `dateFormat`.
http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-defaultDate

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.BirthDate').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-M-y",
        yearRange:'1930:1995',
        buttonImage: '@Url.Content("~/Resource/Calender.jpg")',
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        defaultDate: '01-Jan-95',
        maxDate: '31-Dec-95'
    });
 });
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/VkZrP/2/

Comment: Yes, but you can do it also in the example I posted.

Comment: Also notice the `maxDate` setting since you don't want it going past `1995`